# change specific href and open new window

Tags: jquery, ajax

Looking to change a specific url in the navbar when clicked with a different URL.

I want the user to click 'Contact-Us' and get taken to my main website, but I cannot hard code the wanted link, so I need to use ajax-jquery to change it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').on('click', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'GetUrl',
            async: false,
            success: function (url) {
                $this.attr("href", url);
                $this.attr("target", "_blank");
            },
            error: function () {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    })
})
```

I am unsure if the above code can be used to do this.

Comment: Can you show the html code of contact us .

Comment: `click` event will be long over when the ajax is complete... ajax likely won't complete because of the new page load. Will need to use script to open new window and prevent default

Comment: @charlietfl not necessarily, as he has set the `async` property to false.

Comment: @giorgio right but `async: false` is being deprecated by browsers and may not actually block the event completion. Use of `async: false` is very much discouraged

Comment: One suggestion is since you aren't sending data in request is to get this url before user needs to click on it

Comment: Your code looks good to me except for the semicolons. What is the issue that you're facing ? I've implemented the same in a [bin](http://jsbin.com/nisavaluxe/1/edit?html,output) and it works there

Comment: @Arkantos that demo doesn't represent the same as having `$.ajax` in the event handler. Your code is all synchronous

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should prevent the default behaviour of the 'a' and when you get the url from your ajax call then make the redirection. It's going to be weird from the point of view of the user because there's going to be a delay between the click and the redirection (depending on how long the ajax call takes) but I think it's a solution to your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').on('click', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();// Prevent the default behaviour of a
        $.ajax({
            url: 'GetUrl',
            async: false,
            success: function (url) {
                window.location.href = url;// Force the redirection on success
            },
            error: function () {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'GetUrl',
        async: false,
        success: function (url) {
            window.location.href = url;// Force the redirection on success
        },
        error: function () {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
})
```

});

Turns out this was working fine, I was trying to implement it in Mura CMS, unfortunately it did not like it very much and that is why I was having problems.

Not managed to get it working in my application but you have rested my doubts that I was doing nothing 'wrong'.  I used the code outwith Mura and experienced no problems.

Thanks all